# Proof of convergence of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Problem: Show that if $x_n\to 5$ then $\dfrac{x_n +1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}} \to 3$.

So I know $|x-5|<\epsilon$ and I need to show that $\left|\dfrac{x_n +1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}} -3\right| < \epsilon$.

I tried applying the triangle inequality (and a bit of algebra) to get $$\left|\frac{x_n +1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}} -3\right| \leq |x_n -5| \left |\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}}\right| + \left|\frac{6}{\sqrt{x_n-1}} -3\right|.$$

From this I know that $|x_n -5| <\epsilon$ and can show that $\left |\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}}\right|<1$. So my only problem is the second part of the sum. I have no idea what to do with it to get everything to be less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: This would be much easier if you used the continuity of $(x+1)/\sqrt{x-1}$ at $x = 5$.

Comment: If you use the right theorem about the quotient of convergent sequences, then this problem becomes very easy!

Comment: This also has an answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507230/proving-convergence-using-the-definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_n=\sqrt{x_n-1}$, then $$\left|\frac{x_n +1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}}-3\right|=\frac{|z_n-2|\cdot|z_n-1|}{z_n}=\frac{|z_n-1|}{z_n\cdot(z_n+2)}\cdot|x_n-5|.$$
If $|x_n-5|\lt1$, then $|z_n-1|\lt2$, $z_n\gt1$, and $z_n+2\gt3$, hence $$\left|\frac{x_n +1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}}-3\right|\leqslant\frac23\cdot|x_n-5|.$$